# C++/Tcl Can I retrieve Tcl file line number when a function recorded by Tcl_CreateCommand is invoked

Tags: c++, tcl

I run a Tcl script from a C++ program using `Tcl_EvalFile`. I defined some custom commands (using `Tcl_CreateCommand`), so when they are found in the file a callback is called and then I can run some C++ code (`TclInvokeStringCommand` invokes the callback given to `Tcl_CreateCommand`, the callback type is `int (*executeCmd)( ClientData data, Tcl_Interp *interp, int argc, const char *argv[] )`).

I want to know the script file name and line number within the callback function being invoked.

I could get the script file name using `((Interp*) interp)->scriptFile`.

However, I could not get the script file line number. Is there a way to retrieve this (or compute it in any way)?

Comment: `TclInvokeStringCommand()` is an internal type conversion wrapper to let you use `const char*` for arguments instead of Tcl's real value type, `Tcl_Obj*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information is only exposed at the Tcl level via the [`info frame`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/info.htm#M15) command. (The internal C API for it is sufficiently horrible that it's never been made public.) This means you need to do something like this with `Tcl_Eval()`:

```
// These can be cached safely per thread; reference management is a thing for another question
Tcl_Obj *scriptNameHandle = Tcl_NewStringObj("file", -1);
Tcl_Obj *lineNumberHandle = Tcl_NewStringObj("line", -1);

// How to actually get the information; I'm omitting error handling
Tcl_Eval(interp, "info frame -1");
Tcl_Obj *frameDict = Tcl_GetObjResult(interp);
Tcl_Obj *scriptNameObj = nullptr, *lineNumberObj = nullptr;
Tcl_DictObjGet(nullptr, frameDict, scriptNameHandle, &scriptNameObj);
Tcl_DictObjGet(nullptr, frameDict, lineNumberHandle, &lineNumberObj);

// Now we have to unbox the information
if (scriptNameObj != nullptr) {
    const char *filename = Tcl_GetString(scriptNameObj);
    // Do something with this info; COPY IT if you want to keep past the result reset
}
if (lineNumberObj != nullptr) {
    int lineNumber = -1;
    Tcl_GetIntFromObj(nullptr, lineNumberObj, &lineNumber);
    // Do something with this info
}

// Release the result memory, i.e., the dictionary and its contents
Tcl_ResetResult(interp);
```

Note that neither the `file` nor the `line` keys are guaranteed to be present; the `line` key is usually there, but the `file` key is only there when running code that can be tracked back to a file, i.e., back to `Tcl_EvalFile()` and related.

Comment: Excellent, I pasted your code to my `executeCmd` and it works like a charm. Thanks